# Ansible: install package with version constraint

Tags: ansible, dnf

When installing an rpm package with Ansible how do I specify a version constraint such as `>= 3`?

If for some reason the package is only available in a lower version the package install task should fail.

Comment: Regarding the close vote: Ansible playbooks are written in a programming language. Thus, questions regarding certain aspects of that language are on-topic on SO. See also the other > 16k questions tagged with ansible. My question is about how to implement a package install task with version check in Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make much sense to do that. Indeed, at a given time, your distribution won't have multiple versions of a same package available in the repos. Maybe you can have duplicates but only if a package is available from multiple repos, each with a different version.

See for example [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151690) which explains that with more details.

You could have different packages, for example python34 and python36, but they are not different versions of the same package, they are different packages.

So in conclusion you can't really do that with ansible because at system level it does not make much sense.

Comment: One might think that. But the reality is not that simple. The system package manager might simply miss some recent package versions at a given time for a variety of reason. For example, repositories you expect are enabled aren't. Or due to network issues, proxied local repositories etc. newer version simply aren't locally available via the package manager. If you know that you require a certain minimum version then for sure you want to detect mismatches early on.

Comment: Tou should make sure that proper repos are configured etc, probably within your role or playbook. I understand your concern but what I answered is still true, you won’t be able to express directly the constraint. An approach could be to retrieve the version available currently on the system, assign to a variable, and then do the install task only when the version match.